# Type casting complicated QGraphicsItem

Tags: squish

I have a complicated QGraphicsItem that is visible to Squish, the shape of my object is like this:

> Object is visible on the canvas like this
>       "-----------------o....." this object is exposed by Squish as          QGraphicsItem but this object is constructed of three sub-objects
>       1.) "-----------------" = drawPosVector(QPainter *painter);
>       2.) "o" = QPixmap m_symbol;
>       3.) "....." = drawHistoryTrail(QPainter *painter)

The think I want to be able to select is just "o" = QPixmap m_symbol
So my idea was to typecast the QGraphicsItem and select just "o",
but I'm not able to do that, and Squish detects this object to big for me.

I have a zooming in/out function and when zooming in I can not click on the object. I don't want to rely on Squish (x, y) coordinates, I just want to cast this object and select just the "o", is this possible for such a complicated QGraphicsItem ?

Any help here would be much appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

So, you said that :

> 1.) "-----------------" = drawPosVector(QPainter *painter); 2.) "o" = QPixmap m_symbol; 3.) "....." = drawHistoryTrail(QPainter *painter)

This means that Squish is identifying your object, even just the "o" one.
To select it, you can use something like ***mouseClick(objectOrName)*** (follow this link for this instruction in other languages: http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/)

Don;t worry that your object will be placed in different X, Y coordonates each and every time. Squish can manage to do this, regardless of the objects position.